# Применение произвольной функции к строкам dataframe накопительным итогом

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть DataFrame с двумя столбцами 'total', 'cashflow'.

```
 timestamp   total   cashflow
                   
2020-06-11  300.61   -300.61
2020-06-12  304.21      0.00
2020-06-15  307.05      0.00
2020-06-16  313.86      0.00
```

Есть функция, которую нужно применить к DataFrame[:1], DataFrame[:2], DataFrame[:3] ... DataFrame[:n], где n - количество строк в DataFrame. При этом в каждом вложенном DataFrame перед применением функции необходимо добавить к значению в последней строке столбца 'cashflow' значение столбца 'total' из той же строки и отфильтровать все нулевые значения.
В итоге нужно получить список значений функции для каждого из вложенных DataFrame.
Я дошел до реализации через цикл, но код работает очень долго.

```
data_xirr_1 = []
df_xirr_copy = data_cashflow['cashflow'].copy()
df_x0 = df_xirr_copy[:1]
for i in data_cashflow.index[1:]:
    df_x0 = df_x0.append(df_xirr_copy[df_xirr_copy.index == i])
    df_xirr = df_x0.copy()
    df_xirr[-1] += data_cashflow['total'][i]
    data_xirr_1 += [xirr_1(df_xirr.loc[np.abs(df_xirr) > 1E-10])]
```

Сама функция работает сравнительно быстро.

```
from scipy import optimize as op

def xnpv(rate, cashflows):
    chron_order = sorted(cashflows, key=lambda x: x[0])
    t0 = chron_order[0][0]  # t0 is the date of the first cash flow

    return sum(cf / (1 + rate) ** ((t - t0).days / 365.0) for (t, cf) in chron_order)


def xirr_1(cashflow, guess=0.001):

    return  op.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r, [(x, cashflow.loc[x]) for x in cashflow.index]), guess)
```

В результате получается список с n-1 значений, где n - количество строк в изначальном DataFrame

```
[76.10327236009363, 5.918598501439627, 22.306438719895517]
```

Есть какие-либо решения, которые могут ускорить применение функции накопительно ко всем вложенным dataframe?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Первый способ, который я нашел - векторизация.
Перевел данные в numpy и так же посчитал в цикле.

На длине массива в 2630 строк, получил выигрыш почти в 8 раз. Но все равно как то долго. Есть ли какие либо еще верхнеуровневые подходы к ускорению?

Pandas в цикле:

```
time_1 = time.time()
data_xirr_1 = []
df_xirr_copy = data_cashflow['cashflow'].copy()
df_x0 = df_xirr_copy[:1]
for i in data_cashflow.index[1:]:
    df_x0 = df_x0.append(df_xirr_copy[df_xirr_copy.index == i])
    df_xirr = df_x0.copy()
    df_xirr[-1] += data_cashflow['total'][i]
    data_xirr_1 += [xirr_1(df_xirr.loc[np.abs(df_xirr) > 1E-10])]

print(f'pandas {len(data_xirr_1)} {time.time() - time_1:.2f} сек.')
```

Numpy в цикле:

```
time_1 = time.time()
df_t = data_cashflow.copy()
df_t['date'] = data_cashflow.index
arr_cashflow = df_t[['cashflow', 'date']].to_numpy()
arr_xirr = []
for i in range(1,len(arr_cashflow)):
    arr_cf = arr_cashflow[:i+1].copy()
    arr_cf[i, 0] += data_cashflow['total'].iloc[i]
    arr_xirr += [xirr([(d,x) for x,d in arr_cf[np.abs(arr_cf[:, 0]) > 1E-10]])]

print(f'{len(arr_xirr)} {time.time() - time_1:.2f} сек')
```

Вывод:

```
pandas 2630 16.54 сек.
numpy 2630 2.52 сек
```